# Placing a translucent-like image in Android

Tags: android, image

How can I place a gray image on top of my whole activity? This gray image must be translucent (meaning the user must still see what is beneath that gray image).

I wanted to created something like the pause menu in most games wherein the background can still be seen and when clicked/tapped, it becomes invisible and continues on with the game. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could open a new activity that has a semi-transparent background. Or open a dialog, and have Android take care of it by itself.

If you want to use the same activity, create an ImageView over the entire activity, load it with a semi-transparent image, and set its visibility to 'gone' until you want it to appear.

Comment: how do i create a semi-transparent image? sorry i am very new here.. just part of our assignment

Answer (score 0):

You could also use FLAG_DIM_BEHIND instead of an translucent image

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DIM_BEHIND

Comment: i am very new here.. can you just give me a very simple implementation of this?